# Linux device tree (AD5628)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree, archlinux-arm

I am trying to use AD5628 Digital to analog converter on my raspberry Pi 3  board . I have enabled the driver for that (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/iio/dac/ad5064.c) in the Yocto kernel .

But when i opened the path `/sys/bus/iio/devices/`

Mentioned in (https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/iio-dac/ad5446)  i am not getting any device0.
I got to know that it is a Device tree issue , So i refereed some  web sites (https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7374261/)  and came to know that i need to add the following Device tree details

```
ad5628-1@4 {
compatible = "adi,ad5628-1";
        reg = <4>;
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
        adi,use-external-reference; 
           };
```

But i am not able to find  where to add this information in the linux kernel . and how to enable the device tree for this so that my DAC device should be detected by Linux .

Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated

Comment: were you able to fix this problem, do you have a dts file that i can look at. it would be awesome if you could share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the DAC connected to your RPi board ? (SPI/i2c.. ??), so you need to add the dac as part of that device.

For example, in the [link](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/iio-dac/ad5446) which you mentioned the dac is connected to the SPI, so similarly on those lines you need  add the DT nodes and also enable the driver in the kernel.

```
   axi_spi_1: spi@42040000 {
          #address-cells = <1>;
          #size-cells = <0>;
          compatible = "xlnx,axi-spi-1.02.a", "xlnx,xps-spi-2.00.a";
           ...
          ad5446@0 {
                 compatible = "adi,ad5446";
                 reg = <0>;
                 spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
                 spi-cpha;
                 spi-cpol;
                 vcc-supply = <&dac_vcc>;
          };
    };
```

Comment: My DAC is connected Via SPI. Currently my DTS looks like this compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

        fragment@0 {
                target = <&spidev0>;
                __dormant__ {
                        status = "disabled";
                };
        };

Comment: fragment@1 {
                target = <&spi0>;
                __dormant__ {
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;
                        status = "okay";

                        ad5064@0 {
                                compatible = "adi,ad5064";
                                reg = <4>;
                                spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
                                adi,use-external-reference;
                                vref-supply = <&vref_supply>;
                                };    }; };

Comment: i have used the DTS mentioned in the comment , but i am not able to get device handle for it ? So weather i should change the DTS  to the mentioned above mentioned dts ?